# MEF doesn´t load DLL

Tags: c#, dll, mef

We fighted multiple days with MEF which doesn´t load a specific DLL.

```
2018-12-10 09:58:32,762 [5] ERROR RfcServer.RfcServer The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.
1) No exports were found that match the constraint: 
ContractName    RfcServer.Definitions.ICryptManager
RequiredTypeIdentity    RfcServer.Definitions.ICryptManager
```

First we enhanced our Application in such away that we used a CustomRefelctionContext to log which types will be "seen" from MEF:

```
public class CatalogFilter : CustomReflectionContext
{

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetCustomAttributes(MemberInfo member, IEnumerable<object> declaredAttributes)
    {
        var memberName = member.ToString();
        var hasExportAttribute = declaredAttributes.FirstOrDefault(f => f is ExportAttribute) != null;

        // Log member name
        Console.WriteLine(memberName);

        // Default: No change
        return base.GetCustomAttributes(member, declaredAttributes);
    }

}
```

An instance of this was given to DirectoryCatalog (CustomReflectionContext). Based on output we come to know our Application does not load a dll.

**We solved**

We provided our Application to another department via zip file in a mail. After extract the files some (not all!) DLLs are marked as "unsafe" and you need to unblock those files:

[Unblock a DLL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcqAM.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by unblock Dlls. In the file properties you can click "unblock".